# Registry functions not working under some circumstances

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I need to programmatically disable Windows Error Reporting in my C++ application. To do this, I want to edit the Windows Registry and write two values to it.

The following code works perfectly on my 32 bit Windows 7 machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void DisableWER()
{
        HKEY key;
        printf("%d\n", RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Windows Error Reporting\\"), &key));

        DWORD val = 1;
        printf("%d\n", RegSetValueEx(key, TEXT("Disable"), 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&val, sizeof(val)));

        RegCloseKey(key);
}

int main()
{
        DisableWER();

        printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
        getchar();
}
```

Both functions succeed (return ERROR_SUCCESS), GetLastError() prints 0, and the required value is set in the registry.

On my VPS the program output is the same, but the registry isn't actually modified - simply nothing happens. I can set the value manually using regedit, so I presume it's not a privilege related problem. The VPS runs Windows Server 2008 R2, 64-bit.

What could be the reason? Is it possible that the VPS host's configuration is interfering with the Windows API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get ERROR_SUCCESS then you **know** that the function succeeded and that the registry was in fact updated.  Do *not* use GetLastError() at all, the registry api doesn't use it.

You are simply looking in the wrong place for the change, a 32-bit process [gets redirected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on a 64-bit operating system.  So first place to look is under the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node registry key.

Build your program to target x64 to avoid this redirection or use the KEY_WOW64_64KEY option in RegOpenKeyEx().  Your program must run elevated to be able to modify this key, use the [appropriate manifest entry (requireAdministrator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx) to activate the UAC prompt.  The SysInternals' Process Monitor utility is excellent to troubleshoot registry access problems.